# Titles not appearing on the ViewControllers navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I am currently using the storyboard interface builder to design my GUI.

My structure looks like following in storyboard

```
-> Navigation Controller -> Tab Bar Controller -> SomeViewController
                                               -> AnotherViewController
```

Navigation Bar and Tab Bar appears fine in the ViewControllers, and the titles are set and visible in the editor, but in simulation the titles *disappear*.

How do i resolve this problem?

FYI: `Navigation Controller` and `Tab Bar Controller` are not bound to any Custom Class.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"YourTitle";
```

Simply put that in viewDidAppear in your ViewControllers.

Comment: What I don't understand is, why does it not work if it's set the initializer?

Comment: When I removed the 'Title' from the view controller's storyboard scene, self.title = "Title" started working again in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 10):

Also You can use this code .

```
self.navigationController.topViewController.title=@"YourTitle";
```

put inside viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call this on the viewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "My Title"
}
```